# Edit value in List (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I writing app for UWP

I download JSON like this

```
public async void Inwork_down()
    {

        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
        //Get all products
        var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                      { "per_page", "100" }, { "status","processing"} }); // Dodelat filtr dlaya teh chto v  rabote


        string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();
        Debug.WriteLine(products);

        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);
        OrdersList = new List<RootObject>(rootObjectData);



    }
```

after that I write all data to list like this

```
 private List<RootObject> ordersList;
    public List<RootObject> OrdersList
    {
        get { return ordersList; }
        set { ordersList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

and display data from List using Bindings like this

```
 <ListView x:Name="OrderList"  ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding OrdersChange, Mode=TwoWay}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemClick="MyClick"  
                      >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid x:Name="GridInf"   Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
```

When I click to element in ListView in xaml  it takes data for clicked element and bind it to TextBox'es in another list view.

Like this:

```
private RootObject ordersChange;

    public RootObject OrdersChange
    {
        get { return ordersChange;}
        set { ordersChange = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

and in xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="DetailsList">
            <StackPanel Height="667" Width="989">
                 <Grid x:Name="DetailGrid"  Height="667" Width="989"  VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="989" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Время и дата заказа" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="214" FontSize="23"  Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="vremyazakaza" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="500,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding OrdersChange.date_created}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="360"  Foreground="White" FontSize="23"/>
```

I need to update value in second ListView and write it to List.

How I can do this?

Comment: What is your `RootObject`? To achieve what you what you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for `RootObject` and use two-way binding in `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: It is implemented @JayZuo-MSFT

Comment: If you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for `RootObject` and used two-way binding in `TextBox.Text` then it should be able to work. If you still have problem, I'd suggest you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue.